# Algolia OR Condition

Tags: php, api, search, algolia

I noticed that separating search terms by a comma results in an AND condition: dog, cat = dog AND cat.
Is there a way to execute an OR condition?

Does this look like it would do the trick?

```
index.search("shirts", {
  "facets": "*",
  "hitsPerPage": 10,
  "facetFilters": [
    "size:M",
    "size:L",
  ],
  "maxValuesPerFacet": 100
});
```

Does this look like it might work for dynamically passing the facet values?  It says in the docs:

> You can also use a JSON string array encoding (for example `encodeURIComponent('[["category:Book","category:Movie"],"author:John Doe"]')` ).

```
"facetFilters": json_encode(["size:M","size:L"])
```

---

For anyone looking for how to search using an OR condition, they are called "OR refinements" in the docs.  Here is some code that worked:

```
$algolia_config_settings = array("facets" => "*",
                                 "facetFilters" => array( array("pa_size:xxs", 
                                                                "pa_size:5xl") ),
                                 "hitsPerPage" => 1000);
```

Comment: in what context are you meaning? we need more info please.

Comment: I'm using PHP but it should work more or less the same as the [link]https://www.algolia.com/ site.  You can try "fast, rid" and it will bring up records with both in the title.  I would like to do an OR search.

Comment: can we see the code behind your search feature? at the moment its a bit 'hold it up to the screen and Ill take a look'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do OR with facet filters and tag filters using the same kind of syntax. You can do that using parentheses in a string or use array that you encode. See the REST API documentation for the [details](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-facetFilters).

Also it is true that the implementation might be different if you use an API client. You should have a look at the specific documentation page (for example the [PHP related documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/php#param-facetFilters))

Comment: So, would something like this fetch products that are available in m OR l sizes?

    $index->setSettings(array(
     "attributesForFaceting" => array("pa_sizes"),
     "facets" => array("pa_sizes"),
    "facetFilters" => "pa_sizes:m,pa_sizes:l)"
   ));

Comment: setSettings is for changing the index settings, not for doing queries. It would more like : $index->search("query", array( "facetFilters" => "(pa_sizes:m,pa_sizes:l)" )

Comment: Hi Bobylito,
Can you tell me how to include a code snippet here?  I'd like to show you one that is doing exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: You can't in comments, you should modify your question.

Comment: Thanks bobylito!  That explains it!
Any ideas on how to dynamically supply the facet values?
That's what the user is searching for...

SEE MAIN QUESTION FOR CODE SNIPPET...

Comment: I will try this out after lunch.  If all goes well, we will call this question officially answered!

Comment: The Algolia PHP docs that I quoted above say to use the encodeURIComponent() function, which does not exist in PHP.  Apparently, rawurlencode() is the equivalent.  Will try...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Algolia PHP library you can add OR filters as:

```
$filters[] = 'option1: value1 OR option2: value2'
```

and then pass this as a second argument to search method.

*Credit goes to Iman Santoso: https://au.linkedin.com/in/iman-santoso-9a6bb016*